# User input validation to only include alphabetical characters

Tags: android, regex, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'd like to have the user type in only alphabetical characters in my autocompletetextview and not be allowed to insert blank characters, or numbers, or symbols.

Currently, the Toast message pops up correctly when I dont put in alphabetical characters, but it is also popping up when the correct input(matching key value in firebase database) is put in.
I think I am having problem doing this because my if statement is currently in a for loop that reiterates every key value in my firebase database(which i have to do for my function to work). Is there any workaround for the user input validation to still work in this situation?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    for (final DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        source = textView.getText().toString();

        if (source.equals(childSnapshot.getKey())) {     
            GlideApp.with(Translate.this).load(childSnapshot.getValue(String.class)).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background).into(imageView);
        } else if(!source.equals(!source.equals("[0-9]+")) {
            Toast.makeText(Translate.this, "No number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if(source.equals("[a-zA-Z_]+")) {
            Toast.makeText(Translate.this, "Invalid text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a function for the `regex` which will test the validity of the input and return `true` or `false` like below:

```
private boolean isValidInput(String someText) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z]+)$");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(someText);
    if(matcher.find())
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    source = textView.getText().toString().trim();

    if( !isValidInput(source) ) {
        Toast.makeText(Translate.this, "Invalid input. Please use alpabetical characters.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    for (final DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        if (source.equals(childSnapshot.getKey()) ) {
           GlideApp.with(Translate.this).load(childSnapshot.getValue(String.class)).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background).into(imageView); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using your method, but the "Invalid Input" still pops up even when I type in the correct input

Comment: @Wolfiebae Hm, that is strange, looking at it now. I edited to add `trim()` to `textView.getText().toString()` so that it trims out any extra whitespaces before and after content

Comment: Edited, I think this is what you wanted. Hm, one question, where is this source coming from. Isn't it supposed to be declared or is it a class property variable that is pre set

Comment: The source is the what the user will type in the autocompletetextview

Answer (score 0):

use

> .getText().toString().trim();

, this is the thing I found while entering email addresses on websites,
If You have space in the end, their validation doesn't seem to works